# JQuery UI Background color animate works on Jsfiddle, not on my site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to change the background color of an accordion header in a function. Here is a demonstration of the functionality that I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/5sYCC/ (I put the change in the document ready just to put it somewhere, but it will not be there in the future.)

[However, here is what happens on my server with the exact same code.](http://www.gtacswim.info/tools/Tests/JQueryUI.aspx) It makes no difference if I reference local copies of JQuery, or Google hosted copies. I can't figure out why the same code works differently in different places, especially when I don't reference local copies of JQuery or JQuery UI.

Link to the page that I am trying to build will be below. (Being prevented from adding too many links.)

Comment: [This is what I am trying to create.](http://www.gtacswim.info/tools/Tests/Default.aspx)The server will post sometimes post some forms that will be invalid and I want to red the panels that need attention, then revert them back when they are addressed.

Answer (score 0):

The code on your site uses a background image for the `<h3>`s but your fiddle only uses a background color, the background image is covering up the background color so your color effect is hidden.

Comment: You are correct. Any idea how to get it to stop doing that without removing the background image from the CSS?  Also, I just though. Doesn't the JFiddle site use the same CSS? I mean, if the css were not there, then the whole thing would just look like regular h3 tags. So why does it work differently on the jsfiddle?

Comment: @user1004944: The image URLs in the CSS don't include hostnames so they all 404. You could add another class that overrides the image and colors: `background-image: none; background-color: ...`. You might need to add `!important` to force the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the URLs about a second later and was like "duh". I am working on trying to do exactly your suggestion but having some difficult finding the right way to do it.

Comment: I got it working as desired but without any background color animation. I am going to ask a different question elsewhere to ask about the animation because it's a different topic. Thanks for the help. Interestingly, it now works on my end, but not on JSfiddle. Here is the code on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v29TR/

Comment: Do you have the extra classes on jsfiddle? I just see the usual pile of jQuery-UI mess. For the animation, you might have to manually remove the background image with `.css()` or something like that.